# TRIM won't turn on Samsung 256GB 840 Pro

Tags: macos, ssd, trim

I've just changed to a SSD and am trying to enable TRIM by following this guide - https://digitaldj.net/blog/2011/11/17/trim-enabler-for-os-x-lion-mountain-lion-mavericks/

Everything executes fine but when I look in "System Information" TRIM support says no. Tried running the commands twice and nothing. I am on 10.9.5

Comment: double check you entry for sudo cp /System/Library/Extensions/IOAHCIFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOAHCIBlockStorage.kext/Contents/MacOS/IOAHCIBlockStorage.original /System/Library/Extensions/IOAHCIFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOAHCIBlockStorage.kext/Contents/MacOS/IOAHCIBlockStorage

Comment: Yup, they are there - http://i.imgur.com/WtDiVSZ.png

Comment: Trim Enabler (that the author of the blog post doesn't like) worked fine for me on all 10.9 versions. But if you don't want to use it, note that 2 of the comments in the blog post suggest that the instructions don't work on 10.9.5 for other people too. Note also the comment below one of the 10.9.5 comments about rebooting twice, that could help.